# headless mode on firefox in selenium webdriver does not respond

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, headless, selenium-firefoxdriver

guys I am trying to open a cite in headless mode in firefox, I have a very simple code but it does not work, when I press run it just shows me nothing.
My code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

web = "https://www.powerplay.com/sportsbook/SOCCER/"
firefox_options = Options()
firefox_options.headless = True

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefox_options)
driver.get(web)
```

Here's the respond that I get:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below works for me :

```
executablePath = r'C:\geckodriver.exe'
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = executablePath, options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.powerplay.com/sportsbook/SOCCER/")
print(driver.title)
```

**O/P :**

```
Soccer Betting | Predictions, Tips & Odds | PowerPlay Canada

Process finished with exit code 0
```